# Create a Script for Download and Install Plugins in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, scripting

In my work they install like 20 Wordpress Sites a month, so i have to download and upload a lots of plugins (always install the same plugins). So i was thinking for create a script or ssh command for download the latest versions of the plugins and installed on my Wordpress.

I was searching a demo script or something (im very new with wordpress) but i cant find something like this, maybe someone can help me or give me a idea how to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) is a great comand-line tool that will help you to automate processes like install plugins in wordpress and much more.

> WP-CLI is the command-line interface for WordPress. You can update plugins, configure multisite installs and much more, without using a web browser

After install wp-cli you can open terminal change directory to your wordpress installation

```
cd /var/www/path-to-your-wordpress-installation
```

Install and activate batch of plugins

```
wp plugin install --activate bbpress woocommerce
```

Comment: Yes, im using WP-CLI and works fine, do u know how to install a batch of plugins with WP-CLI?

Comment: I edit my answer by adding command for install batch of plugins with wp-cli